# Speech library installation error

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I installed the [`speech`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/speech) library. But whenever I'm importing `speech` from Python shell it's giving the error

```
>>> import speech
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import speech
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\speech-0.5.2-py3.4.egg\speech.py", line 55, in <module>
    from win32com.client import constants as _constants
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and installing again?

Comment: It seems the `speech` module has an undeclared dependency on `win32api`. So downloading and installing [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) may help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `pywin32`.

Use `easy_install pywin32` or `pip install pywin32`

Answer (score 0):

The `speech` library requires you to install `pywin32`, as noted in the [requirements section](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/speech#requirements) of the README:

> Requires Windows XP or Vista, and Python 2.4 or 2.5. If you use
>   Windows Vista, you'll need to say "start listening" if Speech
>   Recognition is not awake.
>
> In addition to easy_installing speech.py, you'll need pywin32 (for
>   Python 2.5 or for Python 2.4); and if you're on XP, you'll need the
>   Microsoft Speech kit (installer here).

So download and install [**pywin32**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) before attempting to import `speech`.